# Error retrieving root DSE

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap

I am attempting to write some VBScripts for creating users and adding them to groups in Windows 2012 AD. I need to run these from a second server that is in the Domain, logged in with Administrator privs.

I have installed the Remote Admin tools, and I can use the Windows AD tools to make changes to the AD Users and Groups.  But my LDAP related commands in VBScript will not connect or find the AD to allow me to use the Scripting module to make these changes.

So when I attempt this command:

```
Set objRootLDAP = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
```

I get an error:

> The specified domain either does not exists or could not be contacted.

Can anyone advise as to what I'm doing wrong?   What do I need to get these VBScript LDAP commands to connect and run properly?

Comment: If you have a Server 2012 and the RSAT installed on your client, why aren't you using PowerShell for this?

Comment: I am primarily a DB programmer, so I'm a little outside my comfort zone I admit.  How would Powershell differ from VBScript?  Can you point me to an example?  Basically, I am creating the Script files dynamically, so that I can create and execute from my DB server.   The idea is the system administrator can add new users without having direct access the AD Controller or know much about how it works.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx

Comment: Well, figured out a way using Powershell.   Much easier syntax, and it connects.   Have not figured out why the LDAP VBScript won't work on the remote server.